# AndEngine TimerHandler not starting

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

I am facing same strange issue.The issue is i am creating a simple TimerHandler in AndEngine BaseGaeActivity and registering it with Scene, but its not getting started.I dont know where i am going wrong here is the code.

```
@Override
public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
        throws Exception {
    pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(myScene);
    myScene.attachChild(mySprite);
            myScene.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(0.2f,true, new ITimerCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            mySprite.setPosition(mySprite.getX(), mySprite.getY()+1);

        }
    }));


}
```

Please help me to sort it out.Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it should work, but might be happening slower than you expect? It will only move 10 pixels every second, which is not very fast.

I copied and pasted your code directly into a test project, and I can confirm it works. Its just very slowly moving the sprite down the y axis of the screen.

If you mean to update with each refresh, you may wish to override the onManagedUpdate method of the Sprite something like this: (Example taked from andengineExamples MovingBallExample.java)

```
@Override
    protected void onManagedUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
        if(this.mX < 0) {
            this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityX(MovingBallExample.DEMO_VELOCITY);
        } else if(this.mX + this.getWidth() > MovingBallExample.CAMERA_WIDTH) {
            this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityX(-MovingBallExample.DEMO_VELOCITY);
        }

        if(this.mY < 0) {
            this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(MovingBallExample.DEMO_VELOCITY);
        } else if(this.mY + this.getHeight() > MovingBallExample.CAMERA_HEIGHT) {
            this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(-MovingBallExample.DEMO_VELOCITY);
        }

        super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for you reply friend..I observed the screen for about 10 minutes but the sprite is not getting displaced from its place.I even changed mySprite.setPosition(mySprite.getX(), mySprite.getY()+1); this line to mySprite.setPosition(mySprite.getX(), mySprite.getY()+10);
 still its not getting moved.

Comment: Could you update your question with the entire class? The problem must be somewhere else. 
Also: Try this: move the line "pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(myScene);" after your update handler so that it is called after. See if that makes any difference. I usually use the SimpleBaseGameActivity instead of BaseGameActivity.

Comment: Also, I do not see where you create your scene "myScene". This should be happening in the onCreateScene method.